# Is it portable to reinterpret_cast unsigned char array to struct pointer containing only unsigned chars members in C++

Tags: c++, struct, casting

I am aware that using reinterpret_cast to cast an array of unsigned char to a struct pointer can cause problems because of padding and ordering of bytes on different systems (like in this example)

```
struct SomeData
{
    unsigned char first;
    int second;
};

unsigned char data[5];
// SomeData might be more than 5 bytes because of padding
// We can't be sure second is valid, because of bytes ordering
SomeData* someData = reinterpret_cast<SomeData*>(data);
```

But my question is for a struct having only unsigned char members

```
struct RGB
{
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
};

unsigned char data[3];
RGB* rgbData = reinterpret_cast<RGB*>(data);
```

In this case the struct RGB is kind of the equivalent of unsigned char[3], therefor I would assume there would be no padding. I have tested with g++ and msvc and no padding is added, is this guaranteed?

Comment: Note that the struct might have some alignment/padding.

Comment: With GCC you can force no padding by `__attribute__((packed))`

Answer (score 0):

While the `reinterpret_cast` is well-defined (in that you can `reinterpret_cast` back to the original type safely), accessing the structure members is **undefined behavior** by implication: there is no object of type `RGB`, so there cannot be a member of it to which [to refer](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#6.2.sentence-1).

C explicitly and normatively describes circumstances for which the standard describes no behavior as undefined behavior; C++ merely [implies the implication](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs#defns.undefined-sentence-2) in a note, but it is after all the etymology of “undefined”.